# Can eval() Do Calculus?

Tags: javascript, eval

I'm making a calculator, and I was just wondering if you could have `eval()` do calculus. I just thought that it would be cool if it could. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Calculus?  That's a broad subject.  Do you mean symbolic differentiation and integration?  Numerical differentiation and integration?  Ordinary and partial differential equations?  Integral equations?  Calculus of variations?  You'd like to be able to write Mathematica in Javascript?  Do you realize what you're asking?  How much calculus do you know?  The answer is "yes", but that won't help you.

Comment: `eval` will just *evaluate* javascript. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: @duffymo You don't have to be so mean Dude. We are all peers here.

Comment: Mean?  That's an honest, well thought out answer.

Comment: @duffymo I'm just asking for anything that has to do with calculus, so thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eval function evaluates javascript so yes, it will do what you are asking. However, you are most likely do not even need to use it.

> Do not call eval() to evaluate an arithmetic expression; JavaScript evaluates arithmetic expressions automatically.

[reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Comment: @NathanChan, I am not quite sure what example do you want... do you mean [these arithmetic operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) ? I am at a loss what more I can show you then the MDN documentation pages talk about.

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```js
var x = 10;
var y = 20;
var a = eval("x * y") + "<br>";
var b = eval("2 + 2") + "<br>";
var c = eval("x + 17") + "<br>";

var res = a + b + c;
```

The result of res will be:- 200 4 27

Thanks,
Abhilash